# Should we map enums in multi layer projects?

Tags: c#, enums, mapping

When coding enterprise apps there is always n number of layers. I personally dont like using tools such as AutoMapper. Majority of reasons why I avoid using Automapper are stated here https://cezarypiatek.github.io/post/why-i-dont-use-automapper/

Time-wise it is pretty much the same amount of work, and manually mapping comes with greater benefits IMO.

What I have been doing so far is I would map enums between layers. But i have an issue with that. Each layer would not add additional value/content to enum, it is just plain-old mapping. I hate it, especially due to the fact that if there is no appropriate mapping value, you would have to do one of the following (and non of them is a good solution)

for example
Layer A

```
public enum Sometype
{
    ACTIVE,
    INACTIVE,
    PENDING,
    DELETED
}
```

Layer B

```
public enum Sometype
{
    ACTIVE,
    INACTIVE,
    DELETED
}
```

If you add value PENDING in Layer A and forgot to add PENDING in layer B, your mapping will be broken. To solve this issue you could

a) throw an Exception - not too eager to discover a bug in production    over such a  trivial issue

b) introduce a new enum in Layer B - such    as UNKNOWN (as a default value) - which adds no value to layer B    context ie. what is UNKNOWN status?

c) map enum to default value -    which will almost always be wrong.

**UPDATE**

If we code using based on DDD approach, majority of enums will be located in Domain layer. Extracting essential part of Domain to a new layer doesnt really make any sense, other then ability to reuse Enums in different layer. Adding reference from all layers to Domain layer is something that is possible.

So my question is should we map enums between layers, or should we use the initial enum where originally declared?

Comment: enums can be added to a shared project and used in all layers

Comment: This should be a common type used in both layers, so same type no problems.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad what about when doing DDD? Why would you want to extract essential part of Domain to a new layer?

Comment: We normally have those in the entities in a namespace named Enums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Shared project to share Enums, or any common code between layers. More details on Shared project [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/shared-projects?tabs=windows)

Answer (score 0):

All I can offer on this one is my opinion, but when I am faced with the same problem I use a combination of both solutions. If the enum is really a crosscutting concern then it is shared across project. However, when an enum can be scoped to a layer and then I only need a subset of it in another layer, then it is mapped. Just be careful in the second case I find that when I come back to it a few years later it takes a min to remember what is what ;)